# How to detect when user delete the app from Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, detect

I'm new to using the Facebook SDK and I wondered how detect when the user deletes the app from his Facebook account. Currently if we delete the app, and we want to post something from my app, I'm getting an error message.

Comment: yep, there's a deauthorize url, which is called whenever a user deletes/ deauthorizes your app. there have been many questions on it here in S.O. so please search, and you shall find.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[FBSession renewSystemCredentials:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult result, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        if (result == ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRejected) {
            NSLog(@"Facebook app deleted");
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

Comment: this doesn't ork for iOS 4.X sdk

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#app-deauthorization

- https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
- go to your app's edit screen
- click on advanced in the left side column
- 'Deauthorize Callback' setting should be near the top

> **App Deauthorization**
>
> When a user of your app removes it in the App Dashboard or blocks the
>   app in the News Feed, your app can be notified by specifying a
>   Deauthorize Callback URL in the Developer App. During app removal we
>   will send an HTTP POST request containing a single parameter,
>   signed_request, which contains the user id (UID) of the user that just
>   removed your app. You will not receive an user access token in this
>   request and all existing user access tokens will be automatically
>   expired.

Comment: yes but in the iOS sdk how detect when the Deauthorize Callback was called ?

Comment: Hello I am using PHP SDK, i am already seted that Deauthorize Callback url but i dont get called that url, can you please tell what happened at my side