# How to detect if someone has removed the app from facebook and is revisiting the app?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is one of the test cases, that needs to be verified.

> 5. Someone removes your app from Facebook via app settings and revisits your app. Your app should detect this and prompt the person
>      to log back in. Go to your app and tap on the "Log in with Facebook”
>      button Tap OK to accept the read permissions (and OK again to accept
>      write permissions where applicable) Go to app settings on Facebook and
>      remove your app Repeat steps 1-2 and verify that Facebook Login works

I have found no way to achieve this.  When I remove the app in facebook, my iOS still believes the session is valid.  Here on Stackoverflow seems there was a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611709/how-to-detect-when-user-delete-the-app-from-facebook) this regarding. But the solution provided doesn't seem to work.

This is what I have so far to login. But I can't detect when the user has removed the app on facebook. Any advice please?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
      NSLog(@"Found a cached session");
      // If there's one, just open the session silently, without showing the user the login UI
      [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"]
                                         allowLoginUI:NO
                                    completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                      // Handler for session state changes
                                      // This method will be called EACH time the session state changes,
                                      // also for intermediate states and NOT just when the session open
                                      [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                                    }];

      // If there's no cached session, we will show a login button
    } else {
      UIButton *loginButton = [self.customLoginViewController loginButton];
      [loginButton setTitle:@"Log in with Facebook" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
  }  

- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error
  {
          // If the session was opened successfully
          if (!error && state == FBSessionStateOpen){
            NSLog(@"Session opened");
            // Show the user the logged-in UI
            [self userLoggedIn];
            return;
          }
          if (state == FBSessionStateClosed || state == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed){
            // If the session is closed
            NSLog(@"Session closed");
            // Show the user the logged-out UI
            [self userLoggedOut];
          }
   }
```

Comment: any update on this

Answer (score 0):

If a user goes to Facebook settings and removed the app, Facebook posts to the "deauthorize callback url" that you set up in the app settings. This will include the same signed request as a canvas app, so you can get the id from there and do whatever you need to do to keep track of that user having removed your app.

Comment: I see, but this will be sent to my backend. So I need to implement a way to make iOS asking my backend if the user is still active then?

Answer (score 0):

As @Tom Kincaid said, you can use the Deauthorize Callback mechanism to receive a call from FB to one of your backend endpoint. See the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.1#deauth-callback

You could store the user_ids in a separate table, or having a flag for the removal in your existing user table or object structure.

Then, your app can check upon loading whether the user is still "active", or is marked as having the app removed, and act accordingly.